# Use mapPartitionsWithIndex for DStream - Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea, spark-streaming

I want to do something very simple: to check what is the content of each partition in the first RDD of my DStream.
This is what I'm doing now:

```
SparkConf sparkConfiguration= new SparkConf().setAppName("DataAnalysis").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaStreamingContext sparkStrContext=new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConfiguration, Durations.seconds(1));
    JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> receiveParkingData=sparkStrContext.socketTextStream("localhost",5554);


Time time=new Time(1000);

JavaRDD<String>dataRDD= receiveParkingData.compute(time);

//I get an error in this RDD

    JavaRDD<String>indexDataRDD=dataRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(new Function2<Integer, Iterator<String>, Iterator<String>>() {
        @Override

        public Iterator<String> call(Integer integer, Iterator<String> stringIterator) throws Exception {
            return null;
        }
    });

indexDataRDD.collect();
```

So I want to print the content of each partition and its ID. However, on the `indexDataRDD` I get this message in my IntelliJ IDE: `mapPartitionsWithIndex (Function2<Integer, Iterator<String>, Iterator<String>>, boolean) in AbstractJavaRDDLike cannot be applied to (Function2<Integer, Iterator<String>, Iterator<String>>)`

Can someone help me with this issue? Is there another, easier way to get the content in each partition? I really want to know the specific content of each partition.
Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the reason for the call to `compute(time)`? You *generally* shouldn't be doing that. Remember, a `DStream` has a single `RDD` in it's pipeline for any given batch interval.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample program for mapPartitionsWithIndex for your reference.

```
public class SparkDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkDemo").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList("one","two","three","four","five");
    JavaRDD<String> javaRDD = sc.parallelize(data, 2);
    JavaRDD<String> mapPartitionsWithIndexRDD = javaRDD
            .mapPartitionsWithIndex(new Function2<Integer, Iterator<String>, Iterator<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Iterator<String> call(Integer index, Iterator<String> iterator) throws Exception {
                    LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()){
                            linkedList.add(Integer.toString(index) + "-" + iterator.next());
                        }
                    return linkedList.iterator();
                }
            }, false);
    System.out.println("mapPartitionsWithIndexRDD " + mapPartitionsWithIndexRDD.collect()); 
    sc.stop();
    sc.close();
   }
}
```